# Display Hotkey associated with menuitem

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, osd

I don't use keyboard shortcuts a lot and would like to improve that.

Is there a way to display (like an On Screen Display) a shortcut I could have pressed when selecting a menu item / context menu via mouse so I can try and memorize the shortcut I could have pressed?

Comment: There is [something like it](http://veodin.com/) for Excel and Word on Windows.

Comment: @Duijf thanks for promoting us. did you test the beta? I am one of the founders and would like to get in touch with you and hear feedback!

Comment: @Cilvic I did. You can find my contact information on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

My company [Veodin](http://veodin.com) is working on such a shortcut trainer

Right now we support Word and Excel shortcuts for 2007 & 2010 in English and German.

We will expand the supported applications soon.

Currently the product is in closed beta, you can subscribe to the waiting list [here](http://veodin.com)